# Spring data r2dbc and group by

Tags: spring-data, spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am using the DatabaseClient to perform my sql queries and I don't see how I can do a group by:

```
databaseClient.select()
              .from( myClass.class )
              .matching( where( "row_1" ).is( "value_1" ) )
              //group by row_2 ...
              .orderBy( Sort.Order.desc( "row_3" ) )
              .page( pageable  )
              .fetch()
              .all();
```

Answer (score 4):

A workaround solution using sql directly.

```java
    public Flux<Map<Object, Object>> countByStatus() {
        return this.databaseClient
                .sql("SELECT count(*) as cnt, status FROM posts group by status")
                .map((row, rowMetadata) -> {
                    Long cnt = row.get("cnt", Long.class);
                    Post.Status s = row.get("status", Post.Status.class);

                    return Map.<Object, Object>of("cnt", cnt, "status", s);
                })
                .all();
    }
```

Check the [complete codes](https://github.com/hantsy/spring-r2dbc-sample/blob/master/database-client/src/main/java/com/example/demo/PostRepository.java#L52).